# AS3 HTMLRequest Returns HTML Markup with PHP Data

Tags: php, mysql, database, actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to access a MySQL Database from an AIR application via `PHP` file but when I try to access the data returned from the page it comes up as either undefined or HTML markup. I put the PHP code between p tags and it printed the expected result `key1=value1&username=h` (`h` is the test user in my database).

AS3 Class

```
    public class MySQLAccess {

        public var loader:URLLoader;
        public var result:URLVariables;
        public const url:String = "http://www.host.com/";
        private var req:URLRequest;
        public var vars:URLVariables;

        public function MySQLAccess() {
            result = new URLVariables();
            loader = new URLLoader();
            loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onURLComplete);
            //loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,ioerror);
            //loader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatus);
        }

        public function addNewUser(username:String, password:String, email:String) {
            req = new URLRequest(url + "registration.php");
            vars = new URLVariables();
            vars.username = username;
            vars.password = password;
            vars.email = email;
            req.data = vars;
            req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
            loader.load(req);
        }

        public function searchUser(username:String, email:String) {
            req = new URLRequest(url + "getUser.php");
            vars = new URLVariables();
            vars.username = username;
            vars.email = email;
            req.data = vars;
            req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
            loader.load(req);
        }

        public function onURLComplete(e:Event) {
            trace("Accessed " + this.url);
            result = e.target.data;
            trace("" + e.target.data.key1);
            trace (result.username);
        }

        /*public function ioerror(e:IOErrorEvent) {
            trace("Error: " + e.errorID);
        }

        public function httpStatus(e:HTTPStatusEvent) {
            trace(e.status);
        }*/
    }
}
```

PHP

```
    //if (isset($_POST[username], $_POST[email])) {
        //$result = mysqli_query($con, "select username from users where username = '$_POST[username]' or email = '$_POST[email]'");
    //}

    $result = mysqli_query($con, "select username from users where username = 'h'");

    print "key1=value1";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          print '&username=' . $row['username'];
     }

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Output in Flash Console (Some Markup Omitted)

```
Accessed http://www.host.com/
undefined
h</body>
</html><!-- www.serversfree.com Analytics Code -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.bugs3.com/ganalytics.js"></script>

<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

Comment: I looked at the output again and saw that it was outputting the username but with the markup attached to it but it still comes out as null when I try to access the data outside the class with `access.result.username` and why does `result.key1` come out undefined?

Comment: Is this all on the same server? No chance of security issues with flex?

Comment: It is the same server and I did manage to access the username with markup any suggestions on how to prevent that? I'm using flash professional.

Comment: Still not sure why `result.key1` returns undefined but I found that the markup is only returned on the last value passed back so I just added `. "&endValue=none"` to my print statement and it's working fine now

Answer (score 0):

Ah I forgot to answer this for you.

```
function onURLComplete(e:Event):void 
{
    var loader2:URLLoader = URLLoader(e.target);
    var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables(loader2.data);
    trace(variables.key1);
    trace(variables.username);
}
```